# A problem which requires Goniometry, Latitude and Longitude.

Tags: trigonometry

Two observers are situated at the equator, but in different longitudes, respectively -43°55'48" and 45°7'12".  In the same instant, the first observer sees the moon at its zenit, while the second observer sees the moon on the horizon.
Estimate the distance from the Earth and the moon, knowing that the Earth's radius is 6371 km length.
My book provides the following solution: d = 3,84 * 10^5 km

This is my solution but at a certain point I'm stuck...

The sum of -43°55'48" and +45°7'12" gives, in module, 90°2'

I think that the book would say 45° 5' 12" (and not 45°7'12") because so the sum is exactly 90° in module...
Earth radius = 6371 km
Circumference of the Earth: 2 PiGreco * r = 2 PiGreco * 6371 = 40029 km

90° : 360° = x : 40029 km ===> x = 10007,25 Km (distance between the observers)

Is it right?  And then, how could I proceed?

Comment: Why is the angle between -43°55'48" and +45°7'12" not 89°03'00"?  If the angle between them were to be 90°, would that not make the Moon an infinite distance away?

Comment: Please could you help me to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mis calculated. The angle between the observers is $\theta = 89^\circ 03' 00"$, i.e. $89.05^\circ$.

[image]

The distance $OC$ in the diagram is $\dfrac{r}{\cos \theta}$ and will give the expected answer.

If you want $AC$, then subtract $r$ from this.